# React Apollo Error - refetchQueries in one component does not re-render the data in another component but re-renders if its in the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a `Main` Component which renders a list of todos

And `Sidebar` Component which has lots of products which looks like

[image: desktop app for wip chat]

The right side besides `Sidebar` Component is the `Main` Component.

When I add a todo in `Input` box `refetchQueries` works but when I select a new `Product` in the `Sidebar` it doesn't re-render the list of Todos ,i.e, the `Main` Component.

It calls the server & receives the perfect response but re-rendering doesn't happen.

The reason I think is its in a different component. [This issue](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/562)  is exactly what I'm facing.

The complete code is open source & available at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/wip-desktop

The relevant parts are -

## Main.js

[refetchQueries works here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/wip-desktop/blob/master/src/components/Main.js#L154-L161) as it is wrapped with `<Query query={GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT} variables={{ id }} />` component

```
<Query query={GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT} variables={{ id }}>
    <Mutation
        mutation={CREATE_TODO}
        refetchQueries={[
            {
                query: GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT,
                variables: {
                    id: state.get("selectedProduct.id")
                }
            }
        ]}
    >
        {mutate => (
            <Input
                placeholder="Add Todo..."
                value={input}
                onChange={this._onInputChange}
                onKeyPress={e => this._onKeyPress(e, mutate)}
            />
        )}
    </Mutation>
</Query>
```

## Product.js which is inside Sidebar.js

[refetchQueries doesn't work here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/wip-desktop/blob/master/src/components/Products.js#L66-L73) as it is not wrapped with `<Query query={GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT} variables={{ id }} />`

```
<Mutation
    key={v4()}
    mutation={SWITCH_SELECTED_PRODUCT}
    refetchQueries={[
        {
            query: GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT,
            variables: {
                id: product.id
            }
        }
    ]}
>
    {mutate => {
        const highlightedProduct = selectedProduct
            ? product.name === selectedProduct.name
            : i === 0;
        return (
            <Product
                onClick={() => {
                    if (highlightedProduct) return;
                    mutate({
                        variables: { id: product.id, name: product.name }
                    });
                }}
            >
                <Name highlight={highlightedProduct}>
                    {product.name}
                </Name>
            </Product>
        );
    }}
</Mutation>
```

How do I use `refetchQueries` when Mutation does not happen in the same component?

Answer (score 0):

The way I dealt with this issue in a similar scenario was to use `this.props.data.refetch` in the component that was associated with the query. I used `refetchQueries` when the Mutation was updating in a different component. Hope that helps get the ball rolling for you.

Comment: I managed to solved this yesterday but never got the time to post the answer. I'll post an answer tomorrow I think. If anyone wants to see the answer, checkout my repo it has the solution. I basically removed refetchQueries & made a local mutation using apollo-link-state & wrapped the component which was not rendering in the Query component so that it renders when property changes.